# Ember manual addObserver does it require removeObserver

Tags: ember.js

Given the following code, do i need to remove the observer at any point? I feel like i do..

```
App.Views.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    init: function ()
    {
        var self = this;

        // Add observer
        self.addObserver('App.Path.To.ItemsObject', self, self._itemsObserver);

        return this._super();
    },
    _itemsObserver: function(){
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to. You can use the events of **willInsertElement** and **willDestroyElement** for this task. See [Doc of Ember.View](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willInsertElement)